# Read/Write string binary data - BinaryReader

Tags: c#, .net, binary

I wrote the below method to archive files into one file using binary mode:

```
        // Compile archive
        public void CompileArchive(string FilePath, ListView FilesList, Label Status, ProgressBar Progress)
        {
            FileTemplate TempFile = new FileTemplate();
            if (FilesList.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                BinaryWriter Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Create), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
                Progress.Maximum = FilesList.Items.Count - 1;
                Writer.Write((long)FilesList.Items.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i <= FilesList.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    TempFile.Name = FilesList.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
                    TempFile.Path = "%ARCHIVE%";
                    TempFile.Data = this.ReadFileData(FilesList.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text + "\\" + TempFile.Name);
                    Writer.Write(TempFile.Name);
                    Writer.Write(TempFile.Path);
                    Writer.Write(TempFile.Data);
                    Status.Text = "Status: Writing '" + TempFile.Name + "'";
                    Progress.Value = i;
                }
                Writer.Close();
                Status.Text = "Status: None";
                Progress.Value = 0;
            }
        }
```

I read files data using ReadFileData which is in the above method method which return a string of data. (StreamReader) Next up I extract my archive. Everything is done great but the data which will being stored in the extraction method doesn't give me a right data so the extracted files have not right data to show their original functionality.

Extract method:

```
    // Extract archive
    public void ExtractArchive(string ArchivePath, string ExtractPath, ListView FilesList, Label Status, ProgressBar Progress)
    {
        FileTemplate TempFile = new FileTemplate();
        BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(ArchivePath, FileMode.Open), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        long Count = Reader.ReadInt64();
        if (Count > 0)
        {
            Progress.Maximum = (int)Count - 1;
            FilesList.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i <= Count - 1; i++)
            {
                TempFile.Name = Reader.ReadString();
                TempFile.Path = Reader.ReadString();
                TempFile.Data = Reader.ReadString();
                Status.Text = "Status: Reading '" + TempFile.Name + "'";
                Progress.Value = i;
                if (!Directory.Exists(ExtractPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(ExtractPath);
                }
                BinaryWriter Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(ExtractPath + "\\" + TempFile.Name, FileMode.Create), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
                Writer.Write(TempFile.Data);
                Writer.Close();
                string[] ItemArr = new string[] { i.ToString(), TempFile.Name, TempFile.Path };
                ListViewItem ListItem = new ListViewItem(ItemArr);
                FilesList.Items.Add(ListItem);
            }
            Reader.Close();
            Status.Text = "Status: None";
            Progress.Value = 0;
        }
    }
```

The structure:

```
struct FileTemplate
        {
            public string Name, Path, Data;
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: In what way does the data get damaged? I.e:. You say it isn't right: what is different? Note: using ASCII will be very limiting.

Comment: No nothing get damage, I mean everything will be extracted well but e. g. when an icon is archived and when it is extracted the size and the name is correct but when I'm opening that Icon, it shows nothing to me. I got use to do this in VB6 even VB.Net but I don't how should I do this in here.

Comment: Off-Topic: instead of using `Writer.Close()` you can use `using (BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(...)) { ... }`, this cleans up the code a bit and you cannot use the BinaryWriter after closing the file.

Comment: @Felix K, I know thanks for record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using byte arrays for write and safe the data.

Byte array( write )

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(..);
// Write it into your stream
myStream.Write(bytes.Count);
myStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Count);
```

Byte array ( read )

```
Int32 byteCount = myStream.ReadInt32();
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[byteCount];
myStream.Read(bytes, 0, byteCount);
```

Comment: How could you use `File.WriteAllText()` to write *binary* data?

Comment: If you read your file as text you could save it the same way.

Comment: No, you can't. If you read binary file as text using some encoding, and then write it back, you most likely won't get the same bytes. Just don't treat binary data as text.

Comment: Made a quick test and you are right, never got this problem because i'm always using binary-data with byte arrays and not strings.

Comment: Thanks. I think this example is exactly the equivalence of what I was doing in vb6 (in the vb6's way not .net) :)

Answer (score 0):

The example of an icon makes it clear;  you are using string-based APIs to handle data that isn't strings (icons are not string-based). More, you are usig ASCII, so only characters in the 0-127 range would ever be correct. Basically, you can't do that. You need to handle binary data using binary methods (perhaps using the Stream API).

Other options:

- use serialization to store instances of objects with the data properties and a BLOB (byte[]) for the content
- use something like zip (maybe SharpZipLib) which does somethig very similar, essentially

Comment: I think the `byte[]` methods of `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` should work too.

Comment: I think it's possible. I did it in VB.Net but with FileOpen and FileRead not Binary classes but they were in binary mode. So what's the difference? C# hasn't any method like the VB does.

Comment: @MahanGM, C# has exactly the same methods as VB.Net.

Comment: @MahanGM if you use (from your code) ReadString to read something that isn't a string, then you've broken it. If you use ASCII to work with non-ASCII text, then you've broken it. You do both. It isn't a question of VB or not; the code as written is simply wrong

Comment: @svick see : .Data = Reader.ReadString() - it won't work if treated as a string

Comment: @MarcGravell, yeah, I meant using `Reader.ReadBytes(count)` and `Writer.Write(bytes)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Data` can be binary data, then you shouldn't have them in a `string`. They should be a `byte[]`.

When you write a string using the ASCII encoding like you do, and try to write binary data, many of the bytes (treated as Unicode characters) can't be encoded and so you end up with damaged data.

Morale of the story: never treat binary data as text.

Comment: As the matter of the fact, I got use to do this since my previous languages such as VB, they did this operation well. I don't know I should reconsider I think. Thanks.